# How to Input multiple data types and Output multiple data types on one line in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to solve the following problem, answer is appreciate : (python 3)

Prompt the user to input an integer between 0 and 155, a float, a character, and a string, storing each into separate variables. Then, output those four values on a single line separated by a space.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how StackOverflow works: You need to show your work and where you're stuck. It's not for people to write your code for you (or, solve homework / classroom assignments).

Comment: ..no homework done today... you bad boy! Welcome and finish the tour ;-)

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I worked on it. Thank you for the feedback. New to stackoverflow

num = 99

num_float = 3.77

character = input("z")

string = input("Howdy")

print(str(num) + "\n" +  str(num_float)  + "\n" + character  + "\n "+ string)

Answer (score -1):

No one will probably give you a complete program like David said, but try using input() to prompt for each value, turning each value into a string with str(), adding them together with spaces in the middle, and printing the answer.
You don't need to input or output multiple values at once.

Comment: @Sidney, If my answer was helpful, do you think that you could mark it correct?